# Populating ListView with cursor info from database, android app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I am working on a project with 2 other people, and as you can probably guess its a bit tought working with someone elses code.  The app we are developing gets info from the internet, each item consisting of a title, link, post, and date.  This info is read into a cursor and then output all in a single string buffer.  This is obviously useless if you want to display the info neatly in an emulator window.  I was hoping someone could help me understand how to work with the info to make it easy to use (i.e. each entry in one TextView, with all entries in a listview).

```
private void showEvents() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = post.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("SELECT "+TITLE+", "+LINK+", "+POST+", "+DATE+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" "+"ORDER BY "+DATE+" DESC;",null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);

     // Stuff them all into a big string
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");


     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String title = cursor.getString(0);
        String link = cursor.getString(1);
        String post = cursor.getString(2);
        String date= cursor.getString(3);

        builder.append(title).append(": " );
        builder.append(link).append(": " );
        builder.append(post).append(": " );
        builder.append(date).append("\n" ); 

     }


     // Display on the screen
     tv.setText(builder);
     this.setContentView(tv);
 }
```

This code basically just outputs everything, unformmatted onto the screen.  I've been trying to figure how to enter the while loop to capture each entity (which is 1 of title, link,post,date) and go from there.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you read a book.  One that will cover these topics is "Android in Practice", from Manning Publications.

There are several important required elements for this, but the key concept is an "Adapter", which connects views with data.  You would end up defining a POJO to represent the data in each record, and your custom Adapter maps from that POJO into view fields.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you enter this while loop, you are reading another line (because of the moveToNext())

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String title = cursor.getString(0);
    String link = cursor.getString(1);
    String post = cursor.getString(2);
    String date= cursor.getString(3);

    builder.append(title).append(": " );
    builder.append(link).append(": " );
    builder.append(post).append(": " );
    builder.append(date).append("\n" ); 

 }
```